# Python logarithm function returning complex instead of float

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, logarithm

```
from sympy import diff
from math import log

def newt_method(f, a, b, e):
    if f(a) * f(b) >= 0:
        raise Exception("Корені відсутні.")
    iterations3 = 0
    if diff(diff(f(a))) * f(a) > 0:
        x0 = a
    else:
        x0 = b
    while f(x0) > e:
        x0 = x0 - (f(x0) / diff(f(x0)));
        iterations3 = iterations3 + 1
    return x0, iterations3

a = 0.1
b = 2.1
e = 0.001
def F(a): return log(a, 10) + (0.5 * a)

newt_method(F, a, b, e)
```

As far as i know, log function should not return complex data, however the program raises an exception "TypeError: Cannot convert complex to float". Would be grateful to hear an advise.

Traceback:

```
line 12, in newt_method
while f(x0) > e:
line 20, in F
def F(a): return log(a, 10) + (0.5 * a)
raise TypeError("Cannot convert complex to float")
```

Comment: don't mix up `math` and `sympy` like that. Try to work with `sympy` and use for ex `symbol('x', real=True)`, see [doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=symbols#sympy.core.symbol.symbols)

Comment: `math.log` isn't _returning_ a complex number. The error is the result of _calling_ `math.log` with a complex number as argument, in this case a SymPy complex infinity. That infinity in turn arises from `f(x0) / diff(f(x0))`, where you divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

`a` or `x0` are numbers, `f(a)` is a number, symbolic differentiation of a constant expression will at best return zero. Use for instance central difference quotients of first and second order.

Why do you care about a bracketing interval if an initial guess is all that is needed for the Newton iteration?

The test to start at the right side of a concave function only is valid if both first and second derivative do not change their sign over the interval. So there is a 10% (swag) chance that the initial guess was improved by this test.

You should always use the absolute value to test against some error level.

If you go forward with the bracketing idea, for instance to ensure that all values are taken inside the domain of the function, you will have to actually test that all roots of the tangents (aka Newton iterates) you compute fall inside the recent bracketing interval. If that fails, fall back to the secant root or the middle point as in bisection. Then actually shrink the bracketing interval.